# Why arrow keys are not getnerating WM_KEYDOWN message VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am created a custom window and want to handle arrow keys ...

But i don't know why they don't generate wm_keydown message ??

Answer (score 1):

I think for child windows wm_getdlgcode is necessary for getting messages for arrow keys ,but
in case of popup windows it not required.

Answer (score 0):

Is your window derived from CWnd? Are you getting other Windows messages & keyboard messages? Is this a SDI/MDI or dialog based app? Can you post some small sample code? I've written many programs that get keyboard notifications

Comment: ya even i found this problem first time... but i got a work around for it... I have handled WM_GETDLGCODE message and passed parameter for the arrows keys..